# Prevent TypeScript public function calling a private function

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, monkeypatching

I have this class:

```
export class ResourceFactory {
    AlgoliaAppId = "AlgoliaAppId";
    // ...

    private resetParams() {
        this.AlgoliaAppId = "AlgoliaAppId";
        // ...
    }

    public initTemplate(objectName, directiveArgs): Template {
        this.resetParams();  // <-- Can I, in any possible way, prevent this line from running?

        this.AlgoliaAppId = `${this.AlgoliaAppId}${objectName}`;
        // ... [long function content which I don't want to duplicate]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extend the `ResourceFactory` class: I want to change the AlgoliaAppId name and prevent `resetParams` from running. (I cannot edit the original class).

Is there any way to override `resetParams` even though it's private, or at least somehow monkey-patch the initTemplate method so it won't run the line `this.resetParams`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no (clean) way to override a `private` method from a base class you don't have control over. I tried some module augmentation to see if I could change the modifier to `protected` but didn't have much luck; TypeScript seems to want all overloads to have the same modifier.

However, I was able to patch the prototype after the class declaration to hack in an overload, at the cost of including a `@ts-expect-error` comment. Seems to be the path of least resistance for fighting with the compiler. Here's what an example subclass would look like:

```js
class Example extends ResourceFactory {
    AlgoliaAppId = "CustomName";
}

// @ts-expect-error
Example.prototype.resetParams = function resetParams() { 
    // your implementation
}
```

Here's a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CVhogVygWADEUEZoBPOAbwFgAoOFuAQSQHMIkBLFNmDABJACZwAvHABEHbnwFCx0gNxMmrOGCi8AbihjA4UXMBgAFFFBQBbNAAoAlHTgB6AFRxRwAGYp8SPC8NmBIwDbAAHYwBrwQkXDurnAAvurMrGD4AEZ8CHC8kbwwACrhoQbATnQamnAwABa8aAB0JmhmltZ2TmqMtZquyS0jA6lMaf2MyOiYAKIgtqFGoIaRopg4eITEZBTUNRlyPPyCIuJS0gDC+GiUNgBytsCqE+lDcAACMGgAtKBgYAUf5QKDQJgLJZhFraCCUGBUQFtUwWKy2TBSHz4SIUOIJdqdNE9Zy0NzuTwATQIUAKITCEWisXiiWSKSAA) as well.

Comment: Thanks, but as I emphasized in the question, I cannot change the superclass.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread that. There's no (clean) way to override a private method from a base class you don't have control over. I tried some module augmentation to see if I could change the modifier to protected and that didn't work either. However, I was able to patch the prototype after the class declaration to hack in an overload, at the cost of including a `// @ts-expect-error` comment. Seems to be the path of least resistance for fighting with the compiler.

Comment: @Infinity Here's the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CVhogVygWADEUEZoBPOAbwFgAoOFuAQSQHMIkBLFNmDABJACZwAvHABEHbnwFCx0gNxMmrOGCi8AbihjA4UXMBgAFFFBQBbNAAoAlHTgB6AFRxRwAGYp8SPC8NmBIwDbAAHYwBrwQkXDurnAAvurMrGD4AEZ8CHC8kbwwACrhoQbATnQamnAwABa8aAB0JmhmltZ2TmqMtZquyS0jA6lMaf2MyOiYAKIgtqFGoIaRopg4eITEZBTUNRlyPPyCIuJS0gDC+GiUEQBytsCqE+lDcAACMGgAtKBgYAUf5QKDQJgLJZhFraCCUGBUQFtUwWKy2TBSHz4SIUOIJdqdNE9Zy0NzuTwATQIUAKITCEWisXiiWSKSAA). Let me know if that works and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sure. Can you please update your answer? :)

Comment: @Infinity done!

Comment: This is an awesome hack and works like a champ for a few of my use cases.